Underwater Compound Movie
I remember watching a film back in the late 90's early 2000's (on UPN Channel 13 in LA I think), it was an underwater compound film. I recall a scene where a guy is in a room with a snakelike creature, the room is filling up with water and he ends up leaving the room and swimming to another room. I remember him making a point of saying this was "not dangerous" since the room was already pressurized or something like that and he gets away. 
I'm wondering, what is the name of this film?
I've gone out of my way to watch every underwater compound movie I can get my hands on and I do remember a scene like this in one of them (maybe DeepStar Six or Leviathan), but the monster wasn't snakelike.
Any ideas? (I'm quite open to the possibility that it is one of the above I mentioned and my memory is just incorrect, but just in case someone remembers it...)

Have you checked out Sphere? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_%281998_film%29

Abyss? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Abyss

Do you remember specifically that scene in any of those films?

OK.  I do know there's a scene in Abyss where one of the characters swims between the open pools under the station because the doors are blocked.

That might be the one I meant to mention in the post above.

I'm thinking it's Abyss (1989).

The Abyss is a 1989 American science fiction-adventure film written and directed by James Cameron, starring Ed Harris, Mary Elizabeth Mastrantonio, and Michael Biehn. When an American submarine sinks in the Caribbean, the US search and recovery team works with an oil platform crew, racing against Russian vessels to recover the ship. Deep in the ocean, they encounter a new and mysterious species.

There are open pools under the platform they're in for their work underwater and they're regularly discussing the pressure issues in different scenes. I'm pretty sure there's a scene where they need to get out of one room into another area of the platform and they free swim between two pools to do it.
Also, here is an image of the "creature" that's in the station. It's basically a living column of water, controlled by the alien creatures underwater.

Source

No. There are no snakes in Abyss. I am trying to come up with it, not Abyss. Abyss is a classic.

@KenSwaizak You have to admit, the water ropes look a LOT like snakes... the OP says "Snakelike" not "snakes"
